# CGI script not running on server

Tags: python-3.x, cgi

I am learning to work with the cgi package on python and for that purpose I have created the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import cgi

print("<html><head><title>HeyHey</title></head>")

print("<body>")
print("<p>This is an example web server.</p>")
print("</body></html>")
```

The script is saved as `server.py` in `/var/www/cgi-bin`.
The output of `ls -l` is the following:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 vagrant vagrant 170 Apr 21 08:18 server.py
```

So then I start my server with the following command:

```
sudo python3 -m http.server --cgi
```

And when I open the page by going to `0.0.0.0:8000/server.py` the code is not being executed instead it is just shown.
Any ideas what am I doing wrong?
P.S: I am working on Debian.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have configured `httpd.conf` file properly in ordert to execute CGI so it looks something like this?

```
<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
   AllowOverride None
   Options ExecCGI
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
Options All
</Directory>
```

You can also follow the steps mentioned here -> https://www.knowledgehut.com/tutorials/python-tutorial/python-cgi